# I can't watch videos I upload to drupal

Tags: drupal, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I can upload a video to my drupal instance, but when I try to view the video I don't have rights to do so. I discovered that the IIS_IUSR doesn't have Read & Execute rights on the video even though the IIS_IUSR does on the containing directory.

IIS_IUSR has Read & Execute, List folder contents, and Read rights to the directory where files are uploaded to. However when I look at the rights of the uploaded video file (something.mp4), IIS_IUSR only has List folder/read data rights and Windows says these are inherited from the parent object. Include inheritable permissions from the object's parent option is checked.

Here's some more information that may be helpful.
If I try to access a video directly via a url I get this error:
**HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.**
**The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.**

Module **RewriteModule**
Notification **BeginRequest**
Handler **StaticFile**
Error Code **0x80070005**

This seems like a configuration issue someplace, i.e. Drupal, IIS, or Windows.

Any thoughts.

My environment:

- Windows 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5
- Drupal 6.19
- MySQL 5.1.49
- PHP 5.2.14

Someone requested that I post my .htaccess. There are several for the site, but here is the one for the files directory where the videos are uploaded to.

SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

But isn't .htaccess only used with Apache? I'm using IIS, so is the .htaccess even used?

Comment: Are you using a ISAPI filter?

Comment: I don't believe I am using an ISAPI filter. How would I verify yes or no in IIS?

Comment: After some more research, I think this problem has to do with how files are uploaded to a temp directory first and then copied to my files directory under wwwroot. The files seem to be keeping the perms that were applied first in the temp directory. That's my theory now at least and I'm sticking with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the videos to work by changing the temp upload directory that Windows uploads files to before they're moved the web directory. By default Windows uses C:\Windows\Temp and in my case the permissions set on the file were kept when they were moved from Temp to the web directory. I didn't want to set IIS_IUSR permissions on this folder, so I created a different directory right under the C drive and gave it IIS_IUSR read/execute perms. Then I updated my php.ini file to point to this new directory. All's working well now. I think the key was to put this temporary directory outside of Inetpub because I tried this same set up but with the temp directory within Inetpub and it didn't work.

Comment: I have the same issue, have tried this and now both IUSR, and IIS_IUSR have all permissions, but still getting 500 error when looking at the page. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, IUSR has correct permissions but IIS_IUSR does not, so still getting 500 error when looking at the page. Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up changing the Anonymous Authentication user for my website in IIS to ApplicationPoolIdentity and this worked for me (rather than IUSR).